# Remove small interstices on the edges of a polygone

Tags: qgis, algorithm, simplify, generalization, smoothing

How can I remove the white interstices on the edges (and interior) of a polygone or polyline, as represented in the first figure below? I want to get smooth and continuous edges, capturing the global external shape, as represented by the red line in the second figure below. Also, I want to keep the big white interiors.

I've tried the following methods, none of them being sucessful:

- convex hull (vector, geoprocessing tools)
- v.generalize.simplify (GRASS)
- Simplipy plugin

I used different generalisation algorithms, such as Douglas-Peuker, which I think is not suitable for this problem.

I work with QGIS 2.18.4 runing on Windows 10.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Buffer - Debuffer** would fill the interstices, but it will partially fill the holes, too. To protect these holes, extract the holes first, then put them back after buffer-debuffer step.

[image]

1. Original feature
2. Create `Convex hull` which outlines the original feature
3. `Symmetrical difference` to extract interior parts
4. Break-up the interior parts into single parts. Then select holes and save them as a new layer.
5. `Buffer` (positive distance)
6. `Debuffer` (negative distance)
7. `Difference` between (6) De-buffered polygon and (4) holes polygon